# How to handle NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> type (Basic Java, LDAP)

Tags: java, casting, ldap, ldap-query

I want to look up data in LDAP server. When I use the following code, it wants me to have NamingEnumeration (not List, HashMap) and also it forces me to use SearchResult type.

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> values =
dirContext.search("cn=Loggers,cn=config", "(objectClass=*)", searchCtls);
```

When I try to use it, since it is NamingEnumeration type, I don't know how to change that to String.  Is there a way to cast it to String?  I want to use **split()** but it's not a String so doesn't seem to work.

```
for (NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> ne : searchResult) {
                String a = searchResult.split("");   // I want to split.
                if(a.length-1].equals("Logger")){
                String logType = a[a.lenth-2];
                try { 
                     // and then , I will do something with logType
```

As you know, my Java basic is really weak. I'd appreciate any advice on how to change NamingEnumeration type to String? If there are many ways, I want to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract data from NamingEnumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487544/extract-data-from-namingenumeration) for iterating the values in a `NamingEnumeration`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990784/searchresult-in-java for getting attribute values out of a `SearchResult`

Comment: @Hulk   Thank you for your links. One link helped me to get an 'cn' value. I am still stuck with NamingEnumeration <SearchResult> ,  <vector> didn't seem to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to iterate a `NamingEnumeration` is with [`hasMore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/NamingEnumeration.html#hasMore()) and [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/NamingEnumeration.html#next()).

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = 
        dirContext.search("cn=Loggers,cn=config", "(objectClass=*)", searchCtls);

while (results.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult result = results.next();
    Attributes attributes = result.getAttributes();
    Attribute cn = attributes.get("cn");
    //get/iterate the values of the attribute
}
```

The "enhanced for statement (sometimes called the "for-each loop" statement)" cannot be used for them because they implement [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html) instead of the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html)-interface. The reason for this is mostly historic, `NamingEnumeration` exists since Java 1.3, `Iterable` since Java 1.5.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you got me more than half way through.   Instead of Attribute, I had to use javax.naming.directory.Attribute ( I'm trying not to use Unbound SDK) Just one last question.  I still need to turn that cn variable into String because I want to split it.  cn is Attribute type now. how can I change that into  String value.   I want to do something like ' cn.split("")